# Extract data from second table using results from first MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables -

```
DEALS
----------------------------------------------
ID     PHONE_NAME    CONTRACT_NAME
19     iPhone 5      Talk 200
72     Galaxy S4     Talk 300
36     Xperia Z1     Talk 400
---------------------------------------------- etc etc
```

and

```
CONTRACTS
----------------------------------------------
ID     PACKAGE       INCLUDED_VALUE      DATA
11     Talk 200      100 minutes         1GB
23     Chat 750      Free insurance      2GB
63     Talk 400      Free car            700MB
84     Talk 300      Free dog            650MB
---------------------------------------------- etc etc
```

What I'm attempting (in vain) to do is to display the data as such:

```
iPhone 5     Talk 200    100 minutes and 1GB
Galaxy S4    Talk 300    Free dog and 650MB
Xperia Za    Talk 400    Free car and 700MB
```

So basically, I want to display each deal with its information from the deals table and match the CONTRACT_NAME from the DEALS table to the corresponding PACKAGE column (each package is unique, no duplicates) in the CONTRACTS table in order to display the INCLUDED_VALUE and DATA columns along with the regular deal info. So end result would be that instead of just seeing 'iPhone 5 on Talk 200' it would say 'iPhone 5 on Talk 200 with 100 minutes and 1GB data'.

I've tried learning JOINS but my brain has failed me horribly (it's no competition for regular expressions though, lol) - could someone pleaaaaase help?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  DEALS.PHONE_NAME,
  DEALS.CONTRACT_NAME,
  CONCAT(CONTRACTS.INCLUDED_VALUE,' and ',CONTRACTS.`DATA`)
FROM
  DEALS INNER JOIN CONTRACTS
  ON DEALS.CONTRACT_NAME=CONTRACTS.PACKAGE
```

Comment: Thank you! The join works perfectly and I found out how to output the 2 columns as separate strings.. thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve your query with something like this:

SELECT PHONE_NAME, PACKAGE, CONCAT(INCLUDED_VALUE, ' and ', DATA) FROM DEALS a INNER JOIN CONTRACTS b ON a.CONTRACT_NAME = b.PACKAGE

Bye.